# Moving, breathing and Striking in the same round with Barbarian

Tags: optimization, pathfinder-2e, action-economy

I have an concept in mind, a [fire-breathing](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=1272) Kobold Barbarian. For it to be effective, it needs to take advantage of the additional damage of Rage, (so Strike at least once, 1 action) and use breath a weapon<sup>1</sup> (2 actions). However, to be able to include as many enemies as possible (or exclude allies) it usually needs to be able to Stride or Step, which would be another action.

What I found:

- Beastmaster Dedication + Mature Beastmaster Companion<sup>2</sup> lets your mount move (so move you) as a free action at level 4

  - I have many mounted characters, so I would like to avoid this
- Rogue Dedication + Skirmish Strike lets you Step and Strike, which would be perfect at level 12

  - Level 12 is very far away
  - Drows Shootist can get it on level 6, but this Archetype is Uncommon (and Drow is far from ideal for a Barbarian, *and* cannot breath fire)
- Potion of Quickness gives you Haste

  - It is very costly, and not available before level 8
- Various reactions can be used to move

  - I would like to use the reaction for AoO

**What is the earliest solution to cram a Breath, a Stride or Step, and a Strike into one turn?** It does not have to be at-will, once per encounter is fine.

I am interested in PFS legal, preferably common solutions.

---

1. when available
2. or Cavalier dedication

Comment: Are you interested in other level 12ish options, or should answers be strictly limited to better options than you've provided?

Comment: I take any answer that is not worse than the listed ones

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Spellcasting

If you're willing to set your combo up in advance (and gain the continued benefits of the spell), you can gain the ability to [Haste](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=147) yourself using any non-divine spellcasting archetype and their Basic Spellcasting Feat. You can increase the number of times per day you can do this with wand(s) of Haste. This takes until level 8 to come online, with the possibility of doing it slightly early if you get your hands on one or more Wand(s) of Haste (a level 7 item).

### Inventor

At level 12, with the Inventor archetype, you can take Advanced Breakthrough > [Clockwork Celerity](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=3060) (assuming armor or, more likely, weapon innovation) to gain 1 round of Quickened to Step/Stride (armor) or Strike (weapon). This has the Unstable trait meaning you can do it once between resting for 10 minutes unless you succeed at a DC 17 Flat Check, in which case you can use it again immediately, when you wish. You'll likely want to reskin the Inventor to fit your theme, but it is ripe for doing so if you don't dive hard into the Gadget options.

Comment: Gonna see if I missed any good options later, but this is what I could think of quickly

Comment: it seems being mounted is still the best (least resource intensive _and_ earliest) option

Comment: @András Almost definitely, if that's acceptable. Animal Companions (etc) simply get the 4th effective action on your turn sooner than its alloted to PC's by the standard power curve. There are, of course, ways to do 3 actions with 2 Action activities earlier, such as Sudden Charge, but 2 actions for 1 Action activities seem to come online at 6th-8th and only for the classes they apply to.

Answer (score 3):

## [Goblin Scuttle](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=41)

This isn't on your *turn*, per say, and isn't as flexible as Haste. However... Barbarians don't have as much use for their reactions, and since you're probably grabbing [Dragon's Rage Breath](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=148) instead of [Attack of Opportunity](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=145) at level 6 (because why not breath fire better?), that means you likely won't be using your reaction at all until at least 8th level. You could combine with Haste, as @Ifusaso describes, and conveniently that comes online at 8th level. Or you could just upgrade it at 9th level with [Skittering Skuttle](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=49)!

To be clear, you'd need to take:

1. Adopted Ancestry (Goblin) (General Feat at level 3)
2. Goblin Scuttle (Ancestry Feat at level 5)

You can get Adopted Ancestry as a background feat via the [Deep Backgrounds](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=1318) optional rules at the cost of a skill. If you do so, you could grab [Ancestral Paragon](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=753) as your level 3 General Feat, getting access to it two levels earlier, or grab it as your second level 1 Ancestry Feat if you are using the [Ancestry Paragon](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=1336) optional rules. I think the Deep Background is a balanced trade off, so you may be able to convince your GM to allow that; Ancestry Paragon is a straight up power boost, but if your GM is doing Free Archetype you might be able to convince them to trade that for Ancestry Paragon for your character; those should be about equivalent power.